# How do I test for flow / order of execution?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, tdd, rx-swift

I'm trying to add a feature to show loading screen to this code:

```
func connect(with code: String) {
    interactor.connect(with: code)
        .subscribe(onNext: { displaySuccessScreenRelay.accept(()) },
                   onError: { displayErrorScreenRelay.accept(()) } )
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I've made a behavior relay called `loadingScreenShownRelay` ad I know the proper way to do this is like this:

```
func connect(with code: String) {
    loadingScreenShownRelay.accept(true)
    interactor.connect(with: code)
        .subscribe(onNext: { 
                       displaySuccessScreenRelay.accept(())
                       loadingScreenShownRelay.accept(false)
                   },
                   onError: { 
                       displayErrorScreenRelay.accept(()) 
                       loadingScreenShownRelay.accept(false)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Now the question is how do I rearrange the test so that I can test not only the logic but the order of showLoading -> success -> hideLoading?

I can probably test the displays and loadingScreenShown observables separately into 2 tests (ie. one to test the logic of `input-> emit display success / error` and one more to test the `loadingScreenShown`). But how do I know that the order was indeed `showLoading -> success -> hideLoading` ? If I do the tests without regards to the order, I can also do this and the tests will still go green.

```
func connect(with code: String) {
    loadingScreenShownRelay.accept(true)
    loadingScreenShownRelay.accept(false)
    interactor.connect(with: code)
        .subscribe(onNext: { displaySuccessScreenRelay.accept(()) },
                   onError: { displayErrorScreenRelay.accept(()) } )
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imperative code, such as you have, can be difficult to test. You will need to put the entire class under test and you will need a fake Interactor.

A test like this will show that your loading screen relay works:

```
class ExampleTests: XCTestCase {

    func test() {
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        let sut = Example(interactor: FakeInteractor(connect: { _ in
            scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(10, ()), .completed(10)]).asObservable()
        }))
        let result = scheduler.createObserver(Bool.self)

        _ = sut.loadingScreenShownRelay
            .bind(to: result)

        sut.connect(with: "foo")

        scheduler.start()

        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, [.next(0, true), .next(10, false)])
    }
}
```

You can see in the assert that the true event comes before the false event and they are separated by the time units it takes for the interactor to emit.

The above uses the RxTest library.

Comment: Ah, right. I can just use a closure for the interactor and mock it directly. And then use TestScheduler. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Any protocol with a single function is semantically identical to a closure (expect for certain ownership considerations.)